# "Waiting for initial communication packet" error 0 in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL server 5.1.51 on a Linux machine.

The application was working fine for the last 32 days, but since yesterday a number of clients are not able to connect to the database from our application. They are getting the following error:

```
-2147467259 [MySQL] [ODBC 5.1 Driver] Lost Connection to MySQL server 
       at 'waiting for initial communication packet',system error: 0
```

What can I do to fix this? Where is `my.ini` located in Windows XP?

Answer (score 4):

Adding the following database parameter to `my.ini` solved my problem:

```
skip_name_resolve
```

This parameter skips host name resolution during connection establishment with the MySQL database server.

Comment: Wow! Many thanks! You solved my problem. After a black out my machines were unable to dialog to a MySQL server 'cos they got always the "Lost Connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet',system". But, with your advice about "skip_name_resolve" now everything works fine! Thanks again.